# проблема с файлом и resource bundle java

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Я пытаюсь взять Resource Bunble из файла, но при попытке получается ошибка. Подскажите что не так, и как можно пофиксить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

ResourceBundle должен находится в пакете **resources**.

[image: Вид ResourceBundle внутри пакета resources]

А вот так происходит **инициализация**

```
private static ResourceBundle resources;

private static final String PATH = "property/words";

private static void configure() {
    resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(PATH);
}
```

Comment: Хотел поставить плюсов, но что вопрос, что ответ с картинками :(

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov сейчас исправим)